# Microsoft Graph API Teams Chat Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

In Microsoft Teams When I add new users to a chat it creates a new "group" chat (not sure what it's called).

[Add Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx6G4.png)

[Group Chat example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkvYG.png)

Is it possible to create groups like these with the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing and creating Teams Chats via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371462/accessing-and-creating-teams-chats-via-graph-api)

Comment: Hi @Christian, Thanks for your comment I think it would be best if I contact the person who asked that question in the link you sent me, but I;m not sure how to contact him I think I need more reputation points before I can do that, or do you know perhaps know of a way I can contact him?

Comment: There are a number of ways to contact him from his profile page if you have access to see that? As that SO post mentions though, there is no way to initiate 1:1 or group chats via Graph API at the moment. The best we can do is to deep link into the teams app

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by the time this question was asked this was not possible, but right now MS Graph API allows this.

Here is an official link to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

From documentation if you would like to use REST API here is an example

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "chatType": "group",
  "topic": "Group chat title",
  "members": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('8c0a1a67-50ce-4114-bb6c-da9c5dbcf6ca')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('82fe7758-5bb3-4f0d-a43f-e555fd399c6f')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('3626a173-f2bc-4883-bcf7-01514c3bfb82')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please make sure to take care of the Authentication [Microsoft Graph auth overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

There are also [Microsoft Graph SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) availalbe

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such API to create a new chat group yet. There is already a feature request for the same [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/913786-microsoft-teams-free/suggestions/38776681-it-would-be-awesome-l-if-there-is-an-api-functiona). You can watch the space for more updates